# Задержка в анимации

Tags: html, jquery

Как положить в переменную дочерний элемент выбранного объекта? попробовал так:

```js
$('.q1').click(function(){
var $b=$(this);
var $c=('$b span');
});
```

```html
<div class="q1">
<span>123</span>
</div>
```

...не выходит.

Comment: `var $c = $b.find("span");`

Comment: добавьте в Ваш html `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Igor Уже всё необходимое подключено. Спасибо.